# Cabal / Stack ignores ghc-options for custom Setup scripts

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to get Stack working on an Arch system. I've done the usual:

```
pacman -S ghc stack cabal-install
```

And then placed the following in `~/.stack/config.yaml`, so that the system GHC is used and dynamic libraries are used (the packages above do *not* include static libraries):

```
system-ghc: true
ghc-options:
  "$everything": -dynamic
configure-options:
  "$everything":
  - -dynamic
```

But when I try to install something, (i.e. `stack install wai`) I see that it attempts to build a custom Setup script:

```
/usr/bin/ghc-8.6.5 -rtsopts -threaded -clear-package-db -global-package-db -hide-all-packages -package base -main-is StackSetupShim.mainOverride -package Cabal-2.4.0.1 /home/alba/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-mPHDZzAJ.hs /home/alba/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs -o /home/alba/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/tmp-Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.5
```

And my options are not honored, so the build tries to use static libraries (and fails). Is there any way to get Stack/Cabal to use certain options when building `Setup.hs`?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I found the relevant issues; it doesn't seem to be possible:

**[stack: Can't use system GHC without static libraries at all (#3409)](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3409)**
**[cabal: `executable-dynamic: True` should apply to `build-type: Custom` setup #1720](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1720)**

Related: It seems cabal will always attempt to build static + dynamic in some cases, even if you tell it otherwise.

---

For now, a partial solution I ended up using is to force the option with a wrapper.

At ~/.local/bin/ghc-8.6.5 put:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/ghc-8.6.5 -dynamic "$@"
```

Then:

```
cd ~/.local/bin
chmod +x ghc-8.6.5
ln -s ghc{-8.6.5,}

ln -s {/usr/bin,.}/ghc-pkg-8.6.5
ln -s {/usr/bin,.}/runghc-8.6.5
ln -s {/usr/bin,.}/haddock-ghc-8.6.5
```

Make sure it's in your PATH and you're good to go.

Comment: Downvoter(s): I know this isn't a real solution, that's why it's not accepted. But so far I haven't seen a solution to this, so posting it in case it's useful to someone.